# in django project, I need to execute perl script with parameter through java script

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I have created a submit button in a HTML and i want to execute one perl script by name "svntask.pl" while submit the button. Do i need to write separate class or def so that i can call that class or def in java sccript? could anyone please help me..
My button code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myTag() {
        alert("tagging");
        svntasktag.pl 
    }

</script>

 <td class="padded_td">
                         {% if subsystems.untagged %}
                            <!-- input type="button" value="Tag" class="Tag"/-->
                            <form name="tag" class="tag" onsubmit="return myTag()">
                                <input type="submit" value="Tag"/>
                            </form>
                         {% endif %}
                       </td>
```

Comment: i want to run the perl script in the form on submit button. But on submitting I am getting error as CSRF token is missing or incorret. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue my form code is as follows

Comment: <td class="padded_td">
                         {% if subsystems.untagged %} <form method=POST action="/var/fpwork/sudhb/pai_dashboard_BLR/site/test.pl" name="tag_form">
 <input type="submit" name="Create Tag" value="Create Tag" onClick="myTag()"/>
 </form>
 {% endif %}
  </td><script type="text/javascript">
function myTag()
{ 
  var data = new FormData();
   var dynamicInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  dynamicInput.type = "hidden";
  document.tag_form.appendChild(dynamicInput);
  document.tag_form.appendChild(dynamicInput));
  document.tag_form.submit();
 }
</script>